# Firebase: AB testing of content within webview

Tags: android, ios, webview, firebase-ab-testing

I have two quick questions to check here on use of Firebase for mobile app content (in webview)

1. Have anyone done ab testing of content within WebView using
   Firebase?
2. How does Firebase remember visitors of WebView pages? Does
   it use a Mobile advertising id? Is it possible to use any other id
   as a visitor id in Firebase (e.g. CRM id, if testing content within
   logged in area)?

Please let me know if you share any insights here

Let me know if you have any questions

DD